# Stability of the critical points set

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology

Let $F:\mathbb{S}^{2}\times\lbrack0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth
($C^{\infty}$) function and $f_{t}(x)=F(x,t)$. Suppose that $f_{0}=f_{1\text{
}}$is the projection over $z$-axis, so point $P=(0,0,1)$ is an absolute
maximum of both $f_{0}$ and $f_{1}$. Let $A_{t}$ be the critical points set of
$f_{t}$ and let $A=\cup_{t}(A_{t},t)$. My question is whether points $(P,0)$
and $(P,1)$ belong to one and the same component of set $A$? If so, this would
be some kind of stability result for the critical points set under homotopy.

If this is something well-known or a counter-example exists, any references
are welcome. (Of course, the same may be asked in a fairly more general
setting, for manifolds etc...)

Comment: Did you check the projection of a generic sphere eversion?

Comment: No, I didn't check sphere eversion, as I don't really understand it. Is it a counter-example? Anyway, if Q=(0,0,-1) and (P,0), (Q,1) belong to one and the same component of set A, it does work to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_t$ is generic then $A$ is formed by a collection of curves in $S^2\times [0,1]$.
So, $(P,0)$ is connected to either

1. $(P,1)$ --- this happens for the constant $f_t$.
2. $(-P,1)$ --- this happens for the projection of a generic sphere eversion, otherwise the orientation would not change.
3. $(-P,0)$ --- It can not happen --- this follow since the number of critical points counted with singes ("$+$" for min and max and "$-$" for saddle) has to be $2$ for every $t$.

Comment: So, it follows that for arbitrary $f_{t}$ some component of $A$ intersects
both $\mathbb{S}^{2}\times\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{S}^{2}\times\{1\}$, isn't it?
And we may claim such "stability" for any critical point of non zero index?
Thanks for the answer.